# Should I stick onto Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I adopted EF (out of box of .NET 4.5) in my new internet web app.

this app do involve quite some operation over db activities, and involve around 30 or more tables.

my point is this is not a simple school project, where EF typically suit for most needs.

as further I developing this app, I found EF very limited or prohibitive for proper/good db design (especially in term over performance)

1) Include

I encountering the Include feature in the query part. Many data missing is due to missing include setting.

the more I putting in this thing, the more I worry a simple data retrieval is getting more things than I needed in certain function.

2) Validation

I'm adopting Fluent Validation for this need, as I prefer the visitor pattern, where no direct code changes needed over the data code itself.

but then I getting more challenges as I subclassing, I need to workout validation able to respect OOP simple stuff. I managed it, though more complexity and certain things I really dislike in its implementation. I believe this subclass validation issue happened in DataAnnotation as well.

3) Transaction

Now, I need to incorporate proper db transactaction control, and I found this lacking in EF, correct me if I'm wrong.

I used to worked with Enterprise component (COM+ in .NET, long-long time ago), and I can't find the proper (or the lack of it) transaction implementation in EF.

I'm still working on this...

concluding)

I come to realize the only thing EF has helped me in my coding, is the data/entity code generation, which this is common feature over many other tool/framework.

I'm thinking to drop this EF, switch back to pre-EF era approach, adopting stored-proc, still code-generated table class (but not EF or DBML).

I can do without SQL LINQ, as I have many challenges over this in past over performance issue.

I like your opinion that I should stay and stick to EF, for whatever reason that my simple mind can perceive, apart from this ORM, which hardly is realistically working at all.

Comment: Working with transactions in EF 6: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked into Dapper? Dapper is a micro ORM which is super fast. It was developed by Stackoverflow folks (Sam Saffron) and they use it on this site extensively for the very reasons you mention - performance and speed. Here is the link:

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net.

We ditched EF and we use Dapper exclusively. Combined with some other community developed Dapper extensions like Dapper.SimpleCRUD and Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator we can quickly generate POCOs from database while retaining all the advantages that Dapper has over EF. Overall you will be writing a bit more code but the speed of Dapper is almost equivalent to using ADO.NET's SqlDataReader. Here's a link to SimpleCRUD:

https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/

Comment: I would question if Dapper is actually an ORM. It even present's itself as object mapper than full-featured ORM.

Comment: I have been trying to adopt Dapper, but finally gave it up as well. I really don't like the way how it retrieve/query the data. Prefer something with LINQ manner.

Comment: There is no 1 punch solution here. Yes if you use EF you don't have to know SQL since you can use LINQ and EF will translate your LINQ into SQL queries. But that translation has a cost and the cost is time. On the other hand Dapper will make you write more code and you have to know SQL but you will be writing only what you need in your app.

Comment: hows dapper and simpleCRUD working for you after 2 years, Is that still a good choice or have you come across something better? Either a better dapper extension or another data access solution.

Comment: @MoXplod, how about using NPoco in 2021?

Answer (score 2):

I agree EF is less useful when you get beyond a certain stage

If your database is useful beyond your application then design the DB for your enterprise, not just your application.  This is where EF falls down. It does not (cannot) consider the different viewpoints onto the database the other players in need, so you end up with naive indexes and relationships.

My 2c (quick response to a very complex question):

Write SPs (yeah, I know) to manage the data collection, provide useful data sets to your business layer and allow inserts/updates to your underlying tables.  Make sure you write a useful data API though, don't just write CRUD for each table.  That's a pointless waste of time.

Use EF to hook into these SPs.  EF generates useful data classes, gives you a transaction wrapper and quite a few other useful bits & bobs.

Enjoy!

No one tool does everything - pick & choose as circumstances arise.

Comment: what is this EF transaction wrapper? can you explicitly manage it?

Comment: Just this kind of stuff.  I didn't really get the terminology right  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325(v=vs.100).aspx  not that exciting really but it works well enough.

Comment: @YngvarKristiansen  - SPs are Stored Procedures.

Comment: Writing SPs would be a pain because you can't optimize your resultsets, ie paging, skiping, grouping etc.  I would avoid SP's if you have any requirement for optimizing your set results.

Comment: @mmcrae what if that application does not embody all the parts of whatever it is that you are doing? Reports, batch processes, monitors, stuff like that. What if the DB already exists in part? Anyway, my point is that the data needs to exist in its own way beyond and outside of the (often short lived) applications so model your data not your app.

Comment: @DonCheadle, Are you able to control the positioning of columns in table? We define on e AuditableBaseEntity with created by, modified by and inherit that in all domain entities when It generates migration, base class columns come first when querying which are of least interest while retrieving results or opening database table in design view.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I few years ago I'd still suggest any .net/sql newcomer to go with EF because of the linq syntax, it looks sexy...
But that's all about it. There's honestly nothing else you may ever gain from EF.

I know that the temptation of writing C# instead of SQL might sound very useful at the beginning but in fact it's not. No machine-generated sql can ever beat handcrafted piece of SQl beast you end up having at the end of the day :)

Other than that, EF is just eating the memory which is the web server's memory and CPU ,well, in most cases I think, but not sure. Still, it's consuming way more resources performancewise and memorywise.

And I'm entirely fed up to the ears with the heavy heavy 20 pound edmx model GUI. +1 pound for every table :) Loosing so much time keeping the edmx in sync with the actual DB, and what reason for after all? Who said you need all that colorful icons for your tables in VS, really? All that stuff is there just for one and the only reason - to make linq-to-entities possible. To hell with it, I just find original SQL looking in no way less nice or cool.

So, I myself made a decision some time ago - no EF for my personal projects.
No heavy buggy stuff, life's easy when you're taking and making it easy.

Comment: the good part using C# sql is very useful for dynamic sql.
using traditional SQL handcoding is a nightmare.

Comment: @Kelmen that's your opinion.

Comment: The benefit is not simply "you don't have to know SQL," you are also spared from a lot of tedious code writing and the compile-time checking reduces the risk of a lot of mistakes.  Obviously there are tradeoffs but your comparison starts from false premises.  The resources consumed by EF itself are not really that significant; the biggest cost is that the queries it writes are not as efficient as they could be if each were hand-tuned.

Answer (score 0):

I have my own data access layer created using Service stack's ORMlite, and toptensoftware's PetaPoco.

**ORMlite:**

1) Create table from C# class, including relations, constrains etc.. (CodeFirst)

2) Can do Insert, Delete, update etc..

example - Creating table: Employee.EnsureTable()

**Petapoco:**

Providers great SQL wrapper class, I use this instead of linq

for Example: sql.Select("FirstName,LastName").From("Employee").Where("ID=@0",100).AND("Active=@0",1)

I prefer above style than LINQ. This also supports Joins (Cool right?)

*Currently ORM lite is not a free one. But you can get the older version which is free.*

Example:

```
//Creating Entity Class

public class Employee:DatabaseEntity<Employee>
{
    //Define properties
}

//DatabaseEntity is my own base class which provides many helper methods from ORM lite and Petapoco, including many static methods eg:EnsureTable()

//Creating Table

Employee.EnsureTable()

//Adding new entity
Employee e=new Employee();
e.FirstName="Chola"
e.LastName="Raja"
e.Active=true
e.Save()

//Find an employee
e=Employee.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==101 && x.Active==true);
//OR
e=Employee.QuerySingle(sql.Select("FirstName,LastName").From("Employee").Where("ID=@0",100).AND("Active=@0",1))

//update
e.LastName="Raja"
e.Save()

//Delete a entity
e.Delete()

//Transaction
e.AssignProject(project1)  //this method could do many operation on many entities using Transaction scope
```

**Note:** I Could not able to extract code from my project. But you can create your own Base class according to your requirement